# Function for one half of an ellipse (horizontal or vertical)

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Suppose I have an Ellipse like

$$4x^2 + 9y^2 = 36$$

which would be written in [standard form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Standard_equation) as:

$$\frac{x^2}{3^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1$$

How do I create a function that gets:

- the top half of the ellipse only?
- the right half of the ellipse only?

Comment: Try isolating $x$ or $y$ and taking the positive square root branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following suggestion from @Tyma Gaidash,

**Isolate y for bottom (-) and top (+) of ellipse**
$$
\frac{x^2}{3^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1 \\
\frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3^2} \\
\frac{y}{2} = \pm\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{3^2}} \\
y = \pm2\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{3^2}} \\
$$

**Isolate x for left (-) and right (+) sides of ellipse**
$$
\frac{x^2}{3^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1 \\
\frac{x^2}{3^2} = 1 - \frac{y^2}{2^2} \\
\frac{x}{3} = \pm\sqrt{1 - \frac{y^2}{2^2}} \\
x = \pm 3\sqrt{1 - \frac{y^2}{2^2}}
$$